# git push to repository pull from other and when push descard images folder

Tags: git

I build new project I wand to pull  from git repository , discard images folder , push to another git server But I didn't found the best.

If you know please point me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your other answer:

```
git init
git remote add origin remotewithimages
git remote add temp remotewithoutimages

git checkout master
git pull
```

Then, create a branch for deleting the images and add a `.gitignore` file with this line:

```
theimagefolder/
```

Then use these commands.

```
git checkout -b imageremoval
git add .gitignore
git commit
```

Then to keep syncing the other remote (do this anytime)

```
git checkout imageremoval
git pull origin master
git merge --squash origin/master
git commit
git push temp imageremoval
```

Done.

Comment: but when i pull again image will be added

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the images folder from your index and then ignore it from future commits:

```
git rm -r --cached images
echo "images" >> .gitignore
```

this will stop tracking the folder - but the images are still in older commits. Commit this deletion:

```
git commit -m "Removed images"
```

now change to your new git server:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git://new-server.com/me/my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

Try github, gitlab, or bitbucket for git hosting services. Github is the most popular for open-source projects, and gitlab and bitbucket will host private repositories for free.